# Suggest the App for Preventing the Words while Chatter Posting

Tags: appexchange

I have installed Chatter Blacklist. but it was failed. I just want to prevent the words while posting in Chatter post.

Can you find me an alternative Appexchange APP for Chatter Blacklist. I got the issue while installing in Production.